# Meaning of rectangular domain for Separation of Variables

Tags: partial-differential-equations

In my Separation of Variables lecture notes, it is said that we require a rectangular domain for us to apply this method of solving PDEs. What exactly does it mean ?

We have the example where a Circle is not a rectangular domain in Cartesians coordinates but it becomes one in Polar Coordinates.

So the questions are : What exactly is a rectangular domain ?

Cheers !

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: Probably rectangular means that in some choice of coordinates it is rectangular. You unfortunately would probably need to know how to transform into those coordinates to use the result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In $\mathbb R^n$, a rectangular domain simply means a domain of the form: $$ \tag{$\ast$}(a_1,b_1)\times \cdots \times(a_n,b_n)$$ with $a_i<b_i$ for each $i=1,\dots,n$. For $n=2$ this is literally a rectangle and for $n=3$ it is a rectangular prism.

It is common to also call any domain in the form of ($\ast$) except with any combination of open intervals, closed interval, or half-open intervals rectangular i.e. $[0,1] \times [0,1)$ is considered rectangular.

Now for separation of variables, I don't entirely agree with how your lecture notes has phrased it - I think it is better to say that separation of variables is possible for domains that are rectangular possibly after a change of coordinates. For example, your lecture notes seems to suggest that a disk is rectangular! This is silly - what it means is that after converting to polar coordinates, a disk is transformed in to a rectangular region.

Comment: This makes way more sense. And for the lecture notes, it was phrased like you so the mistake was more on my side haha. From what I understand having a rectangular domain in the end allows our equations for each variables to act on the same "segments" regardless of how the others behave. I don't know if that is making sense.